# How to edit a form in Yootheme Zoo?

Tags: zoo

Today someone asked me about a problem with a form on their website. The form is made in Yootheme Zoo. But I can't find the form in the backend. The documentation on Yoothemes website is very narrow on this subject. And Google and Youtube couldn't help me either.
According to the Yootheme site it should be simple to create forms, so I guess I'm crazy. But where in this extension can you create and modify forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form Builder is well hidden in Zoo. When you open Zoo click on right on the cogwheel. Now click on the app (Business Directory in my case). You can edit a form by hovering your mouse over a name (first column) or click on Submission in the next column(Template Layouts).

Answer (score 1):

The forms in ZOO are called "Submissions."  Here is the basic steps for it: https://www.yootheme.com/support/zoo/frontend-submission

If you have something specific you need to do that isn't addressed in there, comment and I can edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @YellowWebMonkey. I found the link as well, but in the backend I can't find the page to modify the form fields. It looks like you can only do this when you create a new form?

Comment: Glad you found it.  Sorry I didn't understand exactly what you were looking for.  I have used ZOO quite a bit if you have any other questions.